# How do I ensure Android browsers honour the filename of attached files

Tags: android, http, firefox, webserver

I'm generating HTTP responses using my custom HTTP web server.
In certain circumstances when sending a file attachment, the filename is not honoured properly by some web clients on Android devices.

Several browsers on Android devices exhibit the fault. All the PC browsers I've tried work just fine.

The files in question are marked text/plain and have a filename "Demo.xml", "Demo.pbn", or "Demo.brf".

The Firefox Android browser saves all these attachments as "Demo.txt".
The Chrome browser fails with the .pbn file, renaming it "Demo.pbn.txt".
The Opera browser names all files correctly.

The headers I'm sending are:

```
Header: Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Header: Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Demo1.pbn"
Header: Content-Length:27203

The simple text of the file after a blank line.
It's all ASCII characters by the way.
The content-length header accurately reflects the length of this text.
```

Are there any headers (other than those shown in the clip above) I should be including?

Edit:
Android 11.
Firefox 111.1.1

Comment: The developers of Web browsers can do what they want. They also need to honor OS limitations and the general rules of filesystems (e.g., cannot have two files with the same name). Hence, there is no way you can guarantee that any particular filename is used.

Comment: Did you try to vary the mime-type to  `text/pbn` (etc ...) — I think, the browsers saving with `*.txt` just prioritize the mime type.

Answer (score 1):

What I discovered.

Changing the Content-Type to "text/pbn" solved the problem.
Although "pbn" is not a registered type, it works.
In fact any unrecognised type works. eg:

```
Content-type: text/rubbish; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Demo1.pbn"
```

It seems the browser ignores any unrecognised type and honours the Content-Disposition filename instead.